# Unable to get similar results with a filter applied specific field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on Elastic Search 6.4.2. I am uploading my index and mapping and my searchable fields are title,content and I want to filter the results by **"test"** field. The values in the test fields are **abce, ghij, klmn**. I want to filter the results with field **"test"** and  value **"ghij"**.

```
PUT /test_index
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 4,
            "number_of_replicas": 1,
            "refresh_interval": "60s",
            "analysis" : {
              "analyzer" : {
                "my_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "my_snow"]
               },
               "blogs_analyzer": {
                 "type":       "stop",
                 "stopwords":  "_english_"
               }
              } ,


              "filter" : {
                "my_snow" : {
                    "type" : "snowball",
                    "language" : "Lovins"
                }
            }
        }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "_source": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "properties": {
                "content": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index": "true",
                    "store": true,
                           "analyzer":"my_analyzer",
                            "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "host": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": "true",
                    "store": true

                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index": "true",
                    "store": true,
                            "analyzer":"my_analyzer",
                            "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"

                },
                "url": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index": "true",
                    "store": true

       },
                "test": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": "true",
                    "store": true
        }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with the below body in order to get the results.

```
POST test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                    "match": {
                        "content": {
                            "query": "sports"

                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "title": {
                            "query": "sports"

                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "term": {
                            "test": "ghij"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I send the above request I am getting lesser records and I use send direct request `GET /test_index/_search?q=sports` I am getting more number of results

Comment: The direct request queries every field in your documents while the book query restricts to just two so this is as expected if the term sports will exist in all the fields

Comment: Hey @an__snatcher , the `query` you've posted works as expected. May I know what is it you are looking for and what is it that you are not observing? If you can update some sample `documents` in the question that would help us to help you. :)